# Emberjs show table cell after click on link

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a table that is built from items in a DB and they contain sensitive information that I don't want to display until you click on a link contained in another table cell.

```
|item1|item2|click to show item3|(hidden span within cell)|
```

When you click on the link in cell 3 it will then show cell 4. I know how to accomplish this in typical jquery, but am not sure how to accomplish this in emberjs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A JS fiddle of your setup would make this easier, but basically you would set a property on your controller from an action.

```
 <span {{action showCell4}}>click to show item3</span>
```

on your controller have the showCell4 action:

```
 actions: {
      showCell4: function() {
           this.set('cell4visible', true);
      }
 }
```

then for the table add a class binding

```
 <td {{bind-attr class="cell4visible:visibleClassName:hiddenClassName">
     sensitive info here
 </td>
```